# How to define a generic function and its return parameter

Tags: generics, f#

I am struggling with a seeming trivial problem concerning generics.

I have these methods

```
 let toTypedCollection r l = 
     l |> List.iter (fun x -> r.Add(x)
     r
 let toRowDefinitions = toTypedCollection (new RowDefinitionCollection())
 let toColsDefinitions = toTypedCollection (new ColumnDefinitionCollection())
```

where

```
public sealed class ColumnDefinitionCollection : DefinitionCollection<ColumnDefinition>
```

and

```
public sealed class RowDefinitionCollection : DefinitionCollection<RowDefinition>
```

Now I get an compiler error telling me that `r.Add`needs to be augmented with type information. So I do this

```
let toTypedCollection (r:DefinitionCollection<_>) l = ...
```

The problem now however is that the resulting signature for `toRowDefinitions` looks like

```
DefinitionCollection<RowDefiniton> -> list RowDefinition -> DefinitionCollection<RowDefinition>
```

That is all fine - except for the return type. I absolutely need to have a `RowDefinitonCollection` instead of `DefinitionCollection<RowDefinition>`

Has anybody an idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Does adding a return type annotation (`toTypedCollection (r:...) l : DefinitionCollection<RowDefinition>`) not work?

Comment: @john: That is what I already get. But I need a RowDefinitionCollection

Comment: try out `let toTypedCollection<'T> (r:DefinitionCollection<'T>) l` or something... and even a forced typecast (to 'T) before returning anything. mayby try to post some fully "running" code example containing all needed code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
let toTypedCollection (r : 'T when 'T :> ICollection<_>) l = 
    l |> List.iter (fun x -> r.Add(x))
    r
```

where `ICollection<_>` is the one from `System.Collections.Generic`, but of course, you could use `DefinitionCollection<_>` if you need the concrete type.

[scrwtp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29490527/4191347) shows a shorter notation to achieve a similar type annotation without naming `'T`: Instead of `'T when 'T :> ICollection<_>`, you can also write `#ICollection<_>`. In this case, `'T` isn't used elsewhere, so this notation is shorter.

There is also the less type-safe way of making `toTypedCollection` inline and adding a static member constraint that `r` needs an `Add` method; but with that, it would work on *any* type with an `Add` method, which usually isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Try `let toTypedCollection<'T> (r: #DefinitionCollection<'T>) l = ...`.

The `#` solves the problem for me on a simple sample, though you might need to annotate `toRowDefinitions`/`toColsDefinitions` to pin down the exact return types as well.

Comment: @robkuz it's a shortcut for "some type when the type is compatible with the following". Basically the same thing as in my answer, just without naming `'T`.

Comment: @robkuz: yes, if you check the function signature, you'll see it now has the same constraint on the first argument's type.

Comment: I added the notation and an explanation to my answer and up-voted this one. I hope that you don't mind.